# Simulating quadrotor with Realsense in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
i am trying to make a real quadrotor with realsense so as to avoid the obstacles, but before that, i think it will be necessary to simulate this in the gazebo to try the algrithm, cause you know, crashing in the real world really costs a lot.
i have been searching for the suitable model for a couple of days, and now i am trying to use hector-quadrotor and equipped with a realsense r200. is it a good idea for my situation? or can anyone give me some tips on how to make it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267781/simulating-quadrotor-with-realsense-in-gazebo/) by [serenade_ray](https://answers.ros.org/users/31399/serenade_ray/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jiaxing](https://answers.ros.org/users/36213/jiaxing/) on 2018-09-25**:
Saw your question about simulation in gazebo. I am going to do the same thing. do you have finished this simulation? I am trying to use hector -quadrotor and equipped with a realsense r200 in gazebo to simulation. but I have no idea to do it. can you give me some suggestion? thank you very much!

**Comment by [serenade_ray](https://answers.ros.org/users/31399/serenade_ray/) on 2018-09-26**:
there was a xacro file of realsense, but i don't see such a file in the package presently. there is a launch file named spawn_quadrotor_with_kinect.launch in hector_quadrotor_gazebo\launch, adapt it to realsense version, and it will work.  if need any help,email me at  whiskysolo@126.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I may suggest RotorS from ETH. They have implemented a lot of algorithms with a various models of multirotors, including a framework for easily transporting the algorithms to a real quad.

https://github.com/ethz-asl/rotors_simulator/wiki

Hope this could help.

---

Originally posted by [Leo Campos](https://answers.ros.org/users/31372/leo-campos/) with karma: 41 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0